# stop filter block from moving to state block on selecting any filter option

Tags: catalog, layered-navigation, filter, catalogsearch, filtered-nav

i am not able to keep the filter on page as i select any one from them. On selecting any filter it moves to the state Block. So, what do i do to keep it from moving to the state block?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out of the box (it would be a nice feature though).
I can recommend [this extension](http://www.manadev.com/seo-layered-navigation-plus) that does what you need and even more than that. Even if it's a paid extension I think it's worth the money.
There is also [this one](http://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html) (also payed ) that does what you need (and again even more).

I like the firs one better but I guess it's just a my opinion.

If you don't want to pay for any of these extensions then you can try to change the state block template and make it look like the filter template but the filtered values will still be moved in the state section. To avoid this you can try to merge the available filters with the state ones but this is a painful and time consuming job.

---

<sub>I'm in now way associated with the extensions providers. I've just used the extensions and like them.</sub>

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks for the reply but i actually want to build one, since i am learning to code on magento and doing this can teach me a lot about magento, that,s why. so, even if you can suggest me where do i need to make changes, it would be enough, since i am not able to trace where are the GET parameter that are passed are handled here in Magento.

Comment: If you are learning Magento this is one of the worst place to start (in my opinion). I suggest starting somewhere else, for example, how layouts work, how models works, how to create a simple module....anywhere but the layered navigation, but if you insist, start digging in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php`, `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/`, `app/code/core/Catalog/Block/Layer/`. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, main problem that i am facing is in tracing the dependencies and sequence of calls that Magento is making initially starting from category Controller then i am not able to trace where and how does it make a call to its Model. I'll learn that up from Basics now.