# How to not remove layered navigation options (which are removed after selecting other filter)

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, filter

My question might be unclear. So first here is an example [in this page](http://www.manadev.com/demo/mod-filters/index.php/apparel/shoes.html)   From **Shoe type** when i select `sandles`, two of color filter options disappears from **Color Type**. which i want not to *disappear* instead i want them to be there with *disabled*.

What i have pointed is, on `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter` getItems() method is returning filter items.

Answer (score 2):

Extending the filter class should do the trick, however each attribute you want to filter over would need to be extended as well, for instance `Price.php`. Just extend the `_getItemsData` again.

```
class Company_Layered_Model_Category extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category
{

    /**
     * Get selected category object
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        // set root category for drop downs.
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
        $rootCatId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();;
        $this->_categoryId = $rootCatId;
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($rootCatId);

        Mage::register('current_category_filter', $category, true);

        return $category;
    }

    /**
     * Get data array for building category filter items
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getItemsData()
    {
        $key = $this->getLayer()->getStateKey().'_SUBCATEGORIES';
        $data = $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->getCacheData($key);

        if ($data === null) {
            $categoty = $this->getCategory();
            /** @var $categoty Mage_Catalog_Model_Categeory */
            $categories = $categoty->getChildrenCategories();

            $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
                //->addCountToCategories($categories); 

            $data = array();
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                if ($category->getIsActive()) {
                    $data[] = array(
                        'label' => Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($category->getName()),
                        'value' => $category->getId(),
                        'count' => $category->getProductCount(),
                    );
                }
            }
            //zend_debug::dump($data);
            $tags = $this->getLayer()->getStateTags();
            $this->getLayer()->getAggregator()->saveCacheData($data, $key, $tags);
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Maintaining a list of all available options to build a `<select>` list with `selected="selected"` elements based on the `GET` Param for the attribute.

**Notes:**
To extend for other options, a new Model and rewrite should be put in place to handle specific attributes. Has not been tested for FPC/caching yet, but should function properly as Blocks are not overridden.

**References:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862967/magento-get-selected-filter-in-layered-navigation
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597448/multi-select-filter-in-layered-navigation
- [stop filter block from moving to state block on selecting any filter option](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13059/stop-filter-block-from-moving-to-state-block-on-selecting-any-filter-option)