# error in catalog view layered navigation filter

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, filtered-nav

This is the block from  my catalogsearch.xml

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

The selected filters are displaying multiple time.I tried changing the type and still no change,
Please Help.
 [image]

**update** :

in my catalog\layer\state.phtml

```
$_filters = $this->getActiveFilters();
count($_filters)
```

is returning me 3 which should be only one .Please help why this is happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the xml for duplicate `catalogsearch.leftnav` block

Comment: <reference name="left">
            <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
  <reference name="left_first">
            <block type="catalogsearch/navigation" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml">
                <block type="core/text_list" name="catalogsearch.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
            </block>
        </reference>   i have this in my catalogsearch.xml

Comment: @Melvin Try this 
<reference name="left"> <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/> </reference> <reference name="left_first"><block type="core/text_list" name="catalogsearch.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" /> </block> </reference>

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop over the `$_filter` results most likely just like the RWD theme does in `state.phtml`

```
$_filters = $this->getActiveFilters();
$_renderers = $this->getParentBlock()->getChild('state_renderers')->getSortedChildren();
?>
<?php if(!empty($_filters)): ?>
<div class="currently">
    <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Currently Shopping by:') ?></p>
    <ol>
    <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
        <?php
        $_rendered = false;
        foreach ($_renderers as $_rendererName):
            $_renderer = $this->getParentBlock()->getChild('state_renderers')->getChild($_rendererName);
            if (method_exists($_renderer, 'shouldRender') && $_renderer->shouldRender($_filter)):
                $_renderer->setFilter($_filter);
                echo $_renderer->toHtml();
                $_rendered = true;
                break;
            endif;
        endforeach;
```

...

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/505e8e982ad5f4fd22005060564cad210aab7b6f/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/layer/state.phtml#L36-L53
- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/505e8e982ad5f4fd22005060564cad210aab7b6f/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/State.php#L51

Also, every filter renderer is where the list of states are collected, and also notice the use of `getItemsCount` instead of native PHP `count`, avoid using `count` on the ORM/Collections as [they have big performance impacts](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Conquer_the_5_Most_Common_Magento_Coding_Issues_to_Optimize_Your_Site_for_Performance.pdf):

```
protected function _initFilter()
{
    if (!$this->_filterModelName) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Filter model name must be declared.'));
    }
    $this->_filter = Mage::getModel($this->_filterModelName)
        ->setLayer($this->getLayer());
    $this->_prepareFilter();
```

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/505e8e982ad5f4fd22005060564cad210aab7b6f/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php#L83

Related:

- [How to show layered navigation filter all time](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88218/how-to-show-layered-navigation-filter-all-time?rq=1)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/71606/69

Comment: I have the same code in my templates

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the file mentioned below, in the current theme
`/app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/catalog/layer/state.phtml`

This is the actual code:

```
$_renderers = $this->getParentBlock()->getChild('state_renderers')->getSortedChildren();
```

Replace by:

```
$_renderers = $this->getParentBlock()->getChild('state_renderers');
```

Comment: that did not help

Answer (score 0):

layout-catalogsearch.xml
Comment out a part of the code, clean the cache.

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
    <label>Quick Search Form</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <!--<reference name="left">-->
        <!--<block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">-->
            <!--<block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />-->
        <!--</block>-->
    <!--</reference>-->
    <reference name="content">
        `enter code here`
```